# How can i add custom button (not add to cart) in product page in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, product-page, custom-button

I want to add a new button to the product page , in which file can I add or should I create a module for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Block, we can display various information related to the product such as: Button, chart, discount, offers & deals, terms and conditions or caution etc.

Firstly, you need to create your custom module and after that you to create block using following code into your catalog_product_view.xml file.
`app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">

        <block class="Vendor\Extension\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry" after="product.info.addtocart"
template="Vendo_Extension::catalog/product/view/file.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Now, you need to create another file and named it as ‘File.phtml’, in which you have to add your custom code which you want to display in your custom block.
`app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\file.phtml`

Lastly, you need to create one block ‘Enquiry.php’ file here. In Which you can add your own logical functions.
`Vendor\Extension\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry.php`

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Muhammad Hasham, of course, but after 5 minutes I’ll mark it, now it doesn't allow, "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes". ;)